# Unterschied der Begriffe "Metzgerei", "Fleischerei" und "Schlachterei"

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung dieser Begriffe? Wenn ja, welchen? Wie steht es mit "Wursterei"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

„Wursterei“ läuft für mich eher unter der Rubrik „Marketinggag“ - irgendwie muss man sich ja von den vielen Metzgereien oder Fleischereien absetzen.

Was die drei Begriffe „*Metzgerei/Fleischerei/Schlachterei*“ betrifft: Der Begriff „Metzger“ soll im süddeutschen Raum stärker verbreitet sein; umgangssprachlich verbindet man damit wohl auch jeweils unterschiedliche Arbeitsschritte - in einer Schlachterei wird man wohl keinen Verkauf von Endprodukten erwarten, ein Metzger muss nicht unbedingt selber schlachten.

Diese Unterscheidung gilt aber anscheinend nicht für das Berufsbild selber. Juristisch betrachtet gibt es (in Deutschland) ausschließlich den „[Fleischer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleischer)“ als einzigen Handwerksberuf in diesem Bereich, in dem eine Meisterprüfung abgelegt werden kann. Der „Metzgermeister“ ist also höchstwahrscheinlich ein „Fleischermeister“.

Comment: Wie Jans Antwort zeigt, ist diese Antwort insofern falsch als man in gewissen Gegenden zum „Schlchter“ geht, um Fleisch zu kaufen.

Answer (score 19):

Die Begriffe unterscheiden sich nach Region, bezeichnen aber umgangssprachlich meist das Gleiche: jemanden, der Fleischwaren verkauft, manchmal auch herstellt.

Laut dem [Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/) (ich freue mich immer wenn ich drauf verweisen kann) sieht die [Verteilung im deutschen Sprachraum so aus](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_2/f09a-b/):

[image: Metzger, Fleischer, Schlachter]

*Wurster* ist hier allerdings leider nicht mit dabei - dazu könnt' ich selber auch nichts sagen.

**Edit** - wer scrollen kann ist klar im Vorteil: 
Weiter unten auf der genannten Atlas-Seite gibt es ein zweites Schaubild, das die Bezeichnung für den "Handwerker, der die Tiere tötet und zerlegt" als Abweichung von den oben genannten regionalen Begriffen darstellt. Hier ist "Schlachter"/"Schlächter" die häufigste Nennung:

[image: Wer tötet und zerlegt die Tiere?]

Comment: Sehr anschaulich, sehr schön! Neben Googles ngram-Suchmaschine ein hervorragendes Visualisierungsangebot.

Comment: Auf jeden Fall! Man muss nur Glück haben, dass sie das entsprechende Wort schon mal in einer Umfrage hatten... Aber sie haben inzwischen echt viel. Man kann bei den Umfragen übrigens auch [mitmachen](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_8/)!

Comment: mhm, ich glaube zum "Metzger" gehört die Herstellung der Wurstwaren etc. schon auch dazu... nur halt nicht unbedingt das schlachten und zerlegen der Tiere.

Comment: @ladybug: guter Punkt, danke! Zur Herstellung gehört ja mehr als nur schlachten und zerlegen. Hab's entsprechend editiert. Wobei es ja leider immer mehr Metzger (wie ja auch Bäcker) gibt, die tatsächlich nur noch verkaufen und nix mehr selbst herstellen... Ich glaube aber nicht, dass z.B. *Metzger* eher noch Waren selbst herstellen als *Fleischer* oder *Schlachter*.

Answer (score 3):

Die ersten drei Begriffe sind vollkommen austauschbar. Eine Wursterei ist ein Betrieb oder ein Teil einer Metzgerei, der ausschließlich Würste herstellt.

Answer (score -2):

In Niederbayern bezeichnet eine "Matz" (helles "a", hochdeutsch wohl "Metze") ein weibliches Schwein also eine Sau, meist eine Muttersau. Ich gehe davon aus, dass sich der Begriff "Metzger" davon ableitet -- Eber kommen ja eher selten auf den Tisch. "Matz" wird daher auch als Schimpfwort für Frauen verwendet ("liderliches Weibsvolk"), kann aber auch positiv gemeint sein ("So a Matz!" für durchtrieben, hinterlistig, aber erfolgreich)